# Airflow schedule interval stuck at '1 day, 0:00:0'

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

I need to change the time my DAG runs at to be midday. I followed the advice from various questions on here and deleted the DAG and uploaded a renamed version with a new `dag_id`. Even though the original DAG was renamed from, say, dag_1.py to new_dag_1.py, THE `dag_id` changed, and the schedule interval was changed from '@daily' to '0 12 * * *' when I upload this new DAG version the schedule part of the homepage for this dag still says '1 day, 0:00:00'.

I uploaded a completely different DAG with these parameters and the schedule interval correctly shows '0 12 * * *' so there must be something in the changed DAG or some metadata that is preventing Airflow from seeing it as new. Other than the name of the dag file that I changed and the changed `dag_id` is there anything else I should have changed for Airflow to let me set this to run at a different time?

EDIT: I have recreated this problem with some generic code:

Here is the first version of the dag: dag_1.py

```
import airflow
import datetime
import logging
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator

YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

default_args = {
    'owner': 'my_name',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['my_email'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0 ,
    'slack_conn_id': 'slack_conn',
    'start_date': YESTERDAY,
    'project_id': 'my_project',
    'dataset_id': 'my_dataset',
    'schedule_interval': '@daily',
}

with airflow.DAG(
        'test_cron',
        catchup=False,
        default_args=default_args,
        tags=['example']
    ) as dag:

    my_empty_operator = DummyOperator(
        task_id='empty_task',
        dag=dag,
    )

    my_empty_operator
```

And the updated version dag_1_2.py

```
import airflow
import datetime
import logging
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator

YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

default_args = {
    'owner': 'my_name',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['my_email'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0 ,
    'slack_conn_id': 'slack_conn',
    'start_date': YESTERDAY,
    'project_id': 'my_project',
    'dataset_id': 'my_dataset',
    'schedule_interval': '0 12 * * *',
}

with airflow.DAG(
        'test_cron_2',
        catchup=False,
        default_args=default_args,
        tags=['example']
    ) as dag:

    my_empty_operator = DummyOperator(
        task_id='empty_task',
        dag=dag,
    )

    my_empty_operator
```

Note I have changed
1.the name of the file
2.the name of the dag_id
3.the schedule_interval

However the new DAG, dag_1_2.py still shows on the UI as having a schedule of 1 day, 0:00:00. How is this possible? For all intents and purposes this is a new DAG (or so it seems?)

Comment: I tried your scenario where I changed the `dag_id` and the value of `schedule_interval` and DAG schedule changes as well. I just overwrote my DAG for the changes to apply. 1.) Are you using Cloud Composer? 2.) How are you updating your DAG? Can you provide the actual steps for it? 3.) Can you provide the actual DAGs when set at `@daily` and `0 12 * * *`?

Comment: I have updated my question to include an example. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scheduling is set to **'1 day, 0:00:00'** (by default) and is not updated because you are defining `schedule_interval` in `default_args`. You should define `schedule_interval` in the **DAG object directly**. See [Airflow scheduling docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/faq.html#what-s-the-deal-with-start-date:%7E:text=Is%20your%20schedule_interval%20set%20properly%3F%20The%20default%20schedule_interval%20is%20one%20day%20(datetime.timedelta(1)).%20You%20must%20specify%20a%20different%20schedule_interval%20directly%20to%20the%20DAG%20object%20you%20instantiate%2C%20not%20as%20a%20default_param%2C%20as%20task%20instances%20do%20not%20override%20their%20parent%20DAG%E2%80%99s%20schedule_interval.).

> The default schedule_interval is one day (datetime.timedelta(1)). You must specify a different
> schedule_interval directly to the DAG object you instantiate, not as a
> default_param, as task instances do not override their parent DAG’s
> schedule_interval.

Your DAG should be updated in this manner:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'my_name',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['my_email'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0 ,
    'slack_conn_id': 'slack_conn',
    'start_date': YESTERDAY,
    'project_id': 'my_project',
    'dataset_id': 'my_dataset',
}

with airflow.DAG(
        'test_cron_2',
        catchup=False,
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval='0 12 * * *', #define schedule_interval in the DAG object
        tags=['example']
    ) as dag:
```